# Ubuntu 18.04 - npm update - Error: canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, apt

Attempted NodeJS versions:

- 13.13.0
- 12.16.2
- 8.10.0

npm version: 6.14.4

Followed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/677498/unable-to-install-latest-nodejs-version-on-ubuntu-14-04
and typed:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.13 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

```
301 verbose stack Error: canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
301 verbose stack Exit status 1
301 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
301 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
301 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
301 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
301 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
301 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
302 verbose pkgid canvas@2.6.1
303 verbose cwd /home/2PG
304 verbose Linux 4.15.0-88-generic
305 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "update"
306 verbose node v13.13.0
307 verbose npm  v6.14.4
308 error code ELIFECYCLE
309 error errno 1
310 error canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
310 error Exit status 1
311 error Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
311 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
312 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Full Log: https://pastebin.com/V3N14w5p

When I type `sudo apt-get install npm`:

[image: sudo apt-get install npm]
Steps to reproduce:

1) Create new DigitalOcean NodeJS droplet (v8.10.0)

2) Drag and drop https://github.com/theADAMJR/2PG using FileZilla

3) Go to the folder and type `npm i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1512). That version of Node is not supported. I suggest you use `12.x`.

If you want to use `13.x`. I was able to install it correctly on `13.1.0`, otherwise you'll need to wait until they update the package to support the version of node you want to use, this is a common issue with all native addons.

Comment: Tried:
```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```
but same result

Comment: hmm, the instalation of Node, has nothing to do with `npm install canvas@2.6.1`, please show exactly all the commands you're executing.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge nodejs*`
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -`
`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`
`npm i`

I believe I typed this to create the problem. Previously my NodeJS was v8 when I typed `sudo apt install nodejs`

Comment: `npm i` on your project trigger the error because you're trying to install that package that is not supported by your node version.

Install Node `12.x`, exit that terminal, open a new one `node -v` check that it's indeed `node 12.x`, clear `node_modules`, run `npm i` again

Comment: Just tried a fresh OS install with Node `v8.10.0`, with the same result.
It's a fresh DigitalOcean droplet.

Comment: Show logs, show everything you're doing. You're doing something that's not on your question, it's impossible to help you without full steps to reproduce. Most likely you have a node package manager also installed and you have a version conflict. Do: `npm --version` & `node -v` and show output

Comment: Added steps to reproduce

Comment: can't reproduce, tested with 8.10.0, 8.11.0, 12.13.0, 13.1.0. It only fails with 13.13.0.

What version of `npm` do you have?

Comment: npm version: 6.14.4

Comment: The `npm` version for `8.10.0` should be `5.6.0` so you have something else installed, probably two versions of node, or you're installing `npm` aside from Node, that's why you're having those issues.

Comment: Install `nvm` https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm and do: `nvm install 12.13.0` and then remove `node_modules` and do `npm i`

Comment: I did `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm i` and the app started. I believe there was an issue with my Windows node_modules folder that I drag + dropped. Thanks for the support though; it seems that Linux deployment is mostly painful lol

Comment: You're welcome. Always clear `node_modules` if you're switching node versions. Or you should do `npm rebuild` instead